# Can I use switch structures in my Hexadecimal to Binary Converter

Tags: java, binary, hex, converters

Im here again to ask question.
Earlier we have to explain our program in some instructor in my school and Thankfully I explained it well. but the problem is the codes that I used is Hashmapping but this was not yet taught to us

So the professor told me that I can use switch structure instead of using Hashmapping but I dont know how i can translate it in switch method..

Can you show me if its possible to create an Switch in my program..

PS: I Know I can used binary built in.. but this is the requirements

thank you

my code:

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Jasper {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        HashMap<Character, String> map = new HashMap<Character, String>();
        map.put('0', "0000");
        map.put('1', "0001");
        map.put('2', "0010");
        map.put('3', "0011");
        map.put('4', "0100");
        map.put('5', "0101");
        map.put('6', "0110");
        map.put('7', "0111");
        map.put('8', "1000");
        map.put('9', "1001");
        map.put('A', "1010");
        map.put('B', "1011");
        map.put('C', "1100");
        map.put('D', "1101");
        map.put('F', "1111");
        System.out.print("Input your Hex Number here : ");
        String userInput = input.readLine();
        String x = userInput.toUpperCase();
        String resultx = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
            char hexVal = x.charAt(i);
            String binary = map.get(hexVal);
            resultx = resultx + "\n" + hexVal + "-" + binary;
        }
        System.out.println("The Binary of " + x + ":" + resultx);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(userInput, 16))`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch       Like what i've said i know i can use in that way but this is the problem..

so my question is it possible to translate in a switch structures instead of using HASHMAP!

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to use a `switch` let's extract it into a method like,

```
public static String charToBin(char ch) {
    switch (Character.toUpperCase(ch)) {
    case '0': return "0000";
    case '1': return "0001";
    case '2': return "0010";
    case '3': return "0011";
    case '4': return "0100";
    case '5': return "0101";
    case '6': return "0110";
    case '7': return "0111";
    case '8': return "1000";
    case '9': return "1001";
    case 'A': return "1010";
    case 'B': return "1011";
    case 'C': return "1100";
    case 'D': return "1101";
    case 'E': return "1110";
    case 'F': return "1111";
    }
    return "Unknown";
}
```

Then you can convert a `String` from hex to binary with a method like,

```
public static String hexToBinary(String in) {
    if (in == null) {
        return null;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : in.toCharArray()) {
        sb.append(charToBin(ch));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Finally, you can test it with something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
         String val = Integer.toHexString(i);
         String cust = hexToBinary(val);
         assert(Integer.parseInt(cust, 2) == i);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it like this:

```
/*ToDo - use your favourite parser to convert your string to an integer*/
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x/*x is type int*/));
```

Very important in software development not to reinvent things. Standard code is also self-documenting.

(Another approach would be to use `>>` repeatedly and use operators like `%`, `|` and `^` to yank out each bit in turn.)

Comment: If you're not allowed to do it this way then let me know by comment or downvote.

Comment: sir know i can use that but my question is if i can use switch instead of using Hashmap

Comment: Good stuff. Must you use either a switch or a hashmap or can you do something else?

Comment: I just wondering if i could use switch structures instead of hashmap
so sir Bathsheba , is it possible? if it is, can u do it for me?

Comment: Elliott has pasted up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
            char hexVal = x.charAt(i);
            String binary;
            switch (hexVal) {
        case '0':
                 binary = "0000";
                 break;
        case '1':
                 binary = "0001";
                 break;
        case '2':
                 binary = "0010";
                 break;
        case '3':
                 binary = "0011";
                 break;
        case '4':
                 binary = "0100";
                 break;
        case '5':
                 binary = "0101";
                 break;
        case '6':
                 binary = "0110";
                 break;
        case '7':
                 binary = "0111";
                 break;
        case '8':
                 binary = "1000";
                 break;
        case '9':
                 binary = "1001";
                 break;
        case 'A':
                 binary = "1010";
                 break;
        case 'B':
                 binary = "1011";
                 break;
        case 'C':
                 binary = "1100";
                 break;
        case 'D':
                 binary = "1101";
                 break;
        case 'E':
                 binary = "1110";
                 break;
        case 'F':
                 binary = "1111";
                 break;
    }
            resultx = resultx + "\n" + hexVal + "-" + binary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous contributors already wrote, you could use several elegant algorithms to provide a proper result, but using a switch() statement a with minimal changes of your code could look like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Jasper {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        System.out.print("Input your Hex Number here : "); 
        String userInput = input.readLine();
        String x = userInput.toUpperCase();
        String resultx = "";
        String binVal;

        for (char hexChar : x.toCharArray()) {

            switch (hexChar) {
                case('0') : binVal="0000"; 
                            break;
                case('1') : binVal="0001"; 
                            break;
                case('2') : binVal="0010"; 
                            break;
                ....
                case('F') : binVal="1111"; 
                            break;
                default : binVal="invalid input";
            }
            resultx = resultx + "\n" + hexChar + "-" + binVal;
        }
        System.out.println("The Binary of " + x + ":" + resultx);
   }
}
```